# "make: the '-j' option requires a positive integer argument"

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

When I am trying to compile a set of *.c files, I am getting following error.
make: the '-j' option requires a positive integer argument

I am using make -j8 as command for compiling. If anyone knows, please help.

The compilation should be successful.

Comment: Please state the *exact* command you are giving. Please also include a [mcve] of the Makefile you are using

Comment: To be clear, please edit your question and _cut and paste_ the command you invoke _and_ the error you receive into it (no screenshots please) so we can see clearly what you're running.  Your statement that you run `make-j8` is clearly not correct (for one thing that is missing the space between `make` and `-j8`).  Please use StackOverflow's formatting facilities to format the pasted code correctly as a code block.

Comment: I think, I made a typing mistake, but now I corrected the question. There was a space present, so the command was "make -j8".

Comment: Path>make -j8
make: the '-j' option requires a positive integer argument
Usage: make [options] [target] ...
Options:
  ....................................................................
This program built for i686-pc-cygwin
Report bugs to <bug-make@gnu.org>